# flink-playground table-walkthrough Permission denied

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

when i docker-compose up -d  table-walkthrough  project

[image]
and the error log
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: `FileNotFoundException: /opt/flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml`

This is probably caused by the file sharing between the host and guest operating systems being incorrectly configured. In particular, the default permissions when using Docker on Windows will cause this failure.

Comment: I used Huawei EulerOS not Docker on Windows

Comment: I change  to centos8 and is ok now 
thanks a lot